# Split Tunnelling for specific external domains

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have a OpenVPN access server (installed from market place) VPN setup and with the split tunneling enabled with in my GCP environment.

Say if i access any website ex: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) the request is going through the Internet instead of VPN tunnel.

Now my scenario where in i have to make a specific domain to route through the VPN tunnel. How will i be able to achieve this with OpenVPN. Is there any supporting softwares required for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the split tunnel concept as specified by the OpenVPN you can find the document [here](https://openvpn.net/for/split-tunneling-with-access-server/).